# Scroll up a certain percent

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I'm wondering if there is any easy way using jquery or javascript to read the current percent that the user is scrolled down a page, and then scroll the user up that percent?

The purpose of this would be:

1. Var scrollPercent = Read Scroll %
2. Resize div that effects vertical height of page
3. Scroll up ScrollPercent

Comment: Scrolling up `ScrollPercent` would just go back to the top of the page...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `element.scrollTop` which will give the vertical offset that has been scrolled.

If your scrolling the `body`  then `element` can be the `document.body` otherwise the relative `element`

Use `element.offsetHeight` & compare with it if you need percentages.

Another avialable option is

```
window.scrollY
```

Once you have this scroll value you can use `jquery animation` to scroll up to the previous location